# Data Model with Class Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am building an application that requires database access. As a result, I’d like to use Entity Framework Code First. I am creating my classes and have a question about inheritance and how it will affect the database creating/access. For example, I have a base class called Building and my Hotel Class inherits from Building. When I create the database, I only want a Table called Hotel. So my question is will EF create columns for the properties in the base class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework supports three approaches to mapping an inheritance hierarchy to a data model.

In order to model Hotel as a standalone table, you would select `TPC` (table per concrete type) that models each non-abstract class as a standalone table.

More details can be found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: You're right, I thought there was a 3rd model but I couldn't be bothered to look it up.

Comment: Its an easy miss and I only knew it because Ive been living and breathing Entity Framework recently

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, LongboatHarry.